# scrollTop not working automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are a couple of questions to scrollTop already out there but I haven't really seen anything resembling my problem.

Using jquery 1.7.2 on an IE9 we have a page with three Tabs (JqueryUI).
The Data is connected and that resulted in us only having the current tab on the page. Changing tabs will remove the unseen one and reload the one we jump into.

The Scroll-Positions are stored correctly in variables on the base page but trying to set that position in the document-ready-function does not work.
An alert shows the correct number, so the function is actually called but the scrollbar does not move.

Calling the same function with a button on the page afterwards however works perfectly.
The document-ready-function on the tab's jsp is quite simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    setAhaScrollbar();
});

</script>
```

and the called function is quite simple as well:

```
function setAhaScrollbar() {
    var scrollWert = $('#scrollbarAnhaengeartikel').val();
    alert(scrollWert);
    $('#anhaengeGridScrollable').scrollTop(scrollWert); 
}
```

Called from document-ready it does nothing. Called from a button later on it works fine.

The div where the scroll position is supposed to be set is defined with overflow: auto and a fixed height

Comment: Can you describe further about what #anhaengeGridScrollable element is? How you place it?

Comment: Is `$('#scrollbarAnhaengeartikel')` an input type?

Comment: anhaengeGridScrollable is a div-element with height 470 px; width 1550 px; overflow auto; position relative no margin, no padding. Pretty basic stuff. It contains up to 100 lines with select-inputs

Comment: Maybe would be helpful if you can post your code on fiddle.

Comment: I have to admit that I don't really know how to use that. The site is a bit low on explanations (at least obvious ones; maybe they are somewhere I haven't seen them)

Comment: please post your html as well

Answer (score 0):

> crollTop( value )
>   Description: Set the current vertical position of the scroll bar for each of the set of matched elements.
>   .scrollTop( value )
>   value
>   Type: Number
>   An integer indicating the new position to set the scroll bar to.

[More Information](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)
As the `documentation`said value should be number.
Try

```
var scrollWert = Number($('#scrollbarAnhaengeartikel').val());
```

or

```
var scrollWert = parseInt($('#scrollbarAnhaengeartikel').val());
```

Comment: I will try that although I do not really understand that calling the function from document-ready will result in a numerical value not being understood as a number while calling the fundtion from a button will work. Maybe Jquery does something strange in document-ready.

Comment: Yep, didn't change a thing.

Comment: @Ernst Fritsch can you provide a `fiddle` link

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was primarily a timing problem. Maybe there were still things going on when document ready fired.

Changing that function to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout("setAhaScrollbar()", 500);
});
```

did the trick so my problem is solved.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and check if 0ms works as well - It might very well be the case. SetTimeout pauses the execution innately which is what I think causes your snippet to work. Shouldn't need an "extra" pause of 500ms :)